# Sass does not compile compile right with more than one project accessing a foundation folder

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, codekit

I'm using CodeKit 2.1.8

I was using Foundation 5.4.6 but got in to some problems and updated to 4.5.7 now I still have some problems but different ones.

I was using Sass version 3.4.7 but downgraded to 3.2.19 after reading this could help. This did not help so I updates back to 3.4.7.

Right now my problem is as follows:

I have foundation installed through CodeKit. I did not alter die bower component files, everything is as is.

I have two projects accessing the bower component folder. My folder structure is as follows:

```
zurb-foundation
  bower_components
  dsl
    css
    img
    js
    scss
    index.html
  header
    css
    img
    js
    scss
    index.html
  .bowerrc
  bower.json
  config.codekit
  package.json
```

The Sass files in both the dsl and header folder are completely identical. But they compile different.
Right now the dsl app.css file has about 15000 rows where the header app.css file has about 5000 rows.
I compared them and there are a lot of differences. All of the styles and components get loaded but it looks like the styles get multiple times in the dsl/app.css. Another difference is that the header folder has no sass-cache folder but the dsl folder has got a folder called sass-cache.

So there are some compilation differences does anyone has encountered this before?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I also posted this question in the Foundation forum. Rafi Benkual provided me with this answer:

> Have you tried Libsass? Here is the recommendation from Codekit:
>   Sass Update
>   "Keep using Libsass to compile Sass files in a Zurb Foundation project because the latest Ruby Sass compiler (3.4.5) is not yet supported by Foundation. This should clear up in the next few weeks. See the link in the 2.1.7 release notes, below, for more information."

In CodeKit 2 you can find "Use the libsass compiler" checkbox under "Other options:" on the .scss file's settings panel (on right).

This worked for me.